# How to git-bisect only commits from a single author?

Tags: git, git-bisect

The problem I'm trying to solve is: I know that between version X and version Y, person P committed a change that broke something.  I know I can git-bisect between X and Y and find the change, but it would be faster and more efficient to filter the binary search to select only commits by author P.  I see that git-bisect can filter to commits on certain paths, but I don't see a way to filter by author.

Comment: Why are you so sure that any particular author made the bug. I have seen situations where the bug was caused by unexpected commits. Also, there should not be that much of a benefit unless this author has very few commits.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss I hear you, and you are right in most circumstances.  However, in this case I have a very strong prior that it was one user who caused it.  As for the benefit, if the ratio of all user's commits to this users' commits is R then the expected value of saved steps is log2(R), and in this case R is usually around 4-8, we can expect around 2-3 steps saved.  Since I'm usually around 5-6 steps, this is significant enough for me that I'd love the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the commits by that user using:

```
git log --author="username"
```

For me info check the [git log documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

I don't think there's a `git-bisect` for users